# Not able to do Insert operation in CRUD

Tags: python, html, django

I am making a CRUD of colors with `color_name` and `color_description`. While trying to insert the details the error below has be shown:

```
{'color_name': [ErrorDetail(string='Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str.', code='incorrect_type')]}
```

below is the insert and show function that I have tried out

```
def show_colors(request):
    showcolors = Colors.objects.filter(isactive=True)
    print(showcolors)
    serializer = ColorsSerializer(showcolors,many=True)
    print(serializer.data)
    return render(request,'polls/show_colors.html',{"data":serializer.data})

def insert_colors(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        insertcolors = {}
        insertcolors['color_name']=request.POST.get('color_name')
        insertcolors['color_description']=request.POST.get('color_description')
        form = ColorsSerializer(data=insertcolors)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print("hkjk",form.data)
            messages.success(request,'Record Updated Successfully...!:)')
            return redirect('colors:show_colors')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return redirect('colors:show_colors')
    else:
        insertcolors = {}
        form = ColorsSerializer(data=insertcolors)  
        if form.is_valid(): 
            print(form.errors)   
        return render(request,'polls/insert_colors.html')
```

model

```
class Colors(models.Model):
    color_name = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    color_description = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

HTML of insert_color

```html
<tr>
  <td>Colors Name</td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="color_name" placeholder="COLORS">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Colors Description</td>
  <td>
    <textarea name="color_description" id="" cols="30" rows="10">

    </textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
```

HTML of show color

```html
<td><b>{{result.color_name}}</b></td>
<td><b>{{result.color_description}}</b></td>
```

I have checked the names assigned and they are matching, so where am I going wrong?

Comment: according to your model, the color_name is foreign key but somehow your request seems to be sending a string instead of int.

Comment: thanks for the help salman!
I am not sure how I commited such a silly mistake there

Comment: No worries, we all make such mistakes from time to time. consider upvoting my comment if it helped.

Comment: hi salman,where is the upvote option?isnt it ususally there at the side?

Comment: you can accept my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your model, the `color_name` is a foreign key but somehow your request seems to be sending a string instead of int, which is causing a mismatch there.

Answer (score 1):

see your model you will find that `color_name` is a `foreignkey` you must give it object not `string` you can edit your `ColorsSerializer` to work with attrs of the `foreignkey` so you can add `strings`